# Kindly help,am having issues when I try to install material UI in my react project

Tags: reactjs

npm ERR!     C:\Users\sammy waweru\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-11-19T09_14_33_601Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\sammy waweru\Desktop\challanges\linked-in clone> npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled

up to date, audited 2099 packages in 41s

163 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

27 vulnerabilities (16 moderate, 9 high, 2 critical)

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
PS C:\Users\sammy waweru\Desktop\challanges\linked-in clone> npm i -S material-ui
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: click-me@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.4.0 || ^16.0.0" from material-ui@0.20.2
npm ERR! node_modules/material-ui
npm ERR!   material-ui@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\sammy waweru\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sammy waweru\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-11-19T09_16_16_671Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\sammy waweru\Desktop\challanges\linked-in clone>

Answer (score 0):

install @mui/material without the other depandencies and check if it work

Comment: I have tried still not working

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a react version that doesn't support material ui.
Try:

```sh
npm i react@latest react-scripts@latest react-dom@latest
```

then try re-installing material ui